# Ошибка: TypeError: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, decimal

```
text = ((69695, 'CASTROL', '156f9d', 'Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', 'Castrol-156F9D-Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', Decimal('1.00'), '', Decimal('684.25'), 0, 13155264, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''), (69695, 'CASTROL', '15667c', 'Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', 'Castrol-15667C-Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', Decimal('40.00'), '', Decimal('599.15'), 0, 13155265, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''))

json.dumps(text)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

При сериализации объектов питона в `json`, [если встречается неизвестный тип объекта](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6dbf23cf7df9c9f7d83be6ffff5719555822776f/json_example/dump__serialization__custom_object__default.py), то будет вызвана функция `default`, которая вернет значение, понятное сериализатору `json`. Например, по умолчанию, можно в строку преобразовывать.

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

data = ((69695, 'CASTROL', '156f9d', 'Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', 'Castrol-156F9D-Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', Decimal('1.00'), '', Decimal('684.25'), 0, 13155264, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''), (69695, 'CASTROL', '15667c', 'Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', 'Castrol-15667C-Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', Decimal('40.00'), '', Decimal('599.15'), 0, 13155265, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''))
print(data)

json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)
print(json_data)
```

Результат:

```
((69695, 'CASTROL', '156f9d', 'Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', 'Castrol-156F9D-Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover', Decimal('1.00'), '', Decimal('684.25'), 0, 13155264, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''), (69695, 'CASTROL', '15667c', 'Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', 'Castrol-15667C-Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное', Decimal('40.00'), '', Decimal('599.15'), 0, 13155265, '', Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), Decimal('0.00'), '7', '', ''))
[[69695, "CASTROL", "156f9d", "Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover", "Castrol-156F9D-Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover", "1.00", "", "684.25", 0, 13155264, "", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "7", "", ""], [69695, "CASTROL", "15667c", "Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное", "Castrol-15667C-Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное", "40.00", "", "599.15", 0, 13155265, "", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "7", "", ""]]
```

---

Более сложный пример описания функции `default`:

```
import json

def my_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return float(obj)

    # Далее можно описывать и другие свои типы, например MyFooFooBar
    # elif isinstance(obj, MyFooFooBar):
    #     return obj.get_super_foo_bar_value()

    # Если не удалось определить тип:
    return str(obj)

json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, default=my_default)
print(json_data)
```

Результат:

```
[[69695, "CASTROL", "156f9d", "Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover", "Castrol-156F9D-Castrol EDGE Professional A5 5W30 (1л) Lаnd Rover", 1.0, "", 684.25, 0, 13155264, "", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "7", "", ""], [69695, "CASTROL", "15667c", "Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное", "Castrol-15667C-Castrol EDGE Titanium 5W30 LL 504.00/507.00 (1L).Масло моторное", 40.0, "", 599.15, 0, 13155265, "", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "7", "", ""]]
```

Comment: спасибо gil9red

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю почему, но по умолчанию стандартная библиотека `json` не поддерживает работу с таким типом данных как `Decimal`. Я бы порекомендовал использовать библиотеку [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson), которая поддерживает данный тип данных "из коробки".

```
pip install simplejson
```

Потом можно использовать примерно так:

```
import simplejson
simplejson.dumps(Decimal('123.456'))
```