# TypeError: Object of type is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

Пытаюсь записать в json объект класса Person вот так:

```
def postUserToJson(user):
    fileName = str(user.FullName) + " - " + str(user.Id)
    file = open(pathUsers + fileName + ".json", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    json.dump(user, file, ensure_ascii=False)
    file.close()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Person' is not JSON serializable
```

Как записать в Json объект класса?

Как его потом правильно десериализовать?

Comment: Сериализация и десериализация объектов класса тема непростая. А по поводу этой ошибки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791719/201445

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка: TypeError: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791712/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-typeerror-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

По ссылке в [данном комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850118/typeerror-object-of-type-is-not-json-serializable#comment1367975_850118) описана причина возникновения данной ошибки, а также что необходимо делать, если надо сериализовать неизвесный энкодеру тип.

Тут приведу пример случая, когда создается типовой класс с набором аттрибутов, который подлежит сериализации.

```
import json

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.attribute = kwargs or None

class PersonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Person):
            return obj.__dict__
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

p = Person('Bob', 30, height=180, width=70)
print(json.dumps(p, cls=PersonEncoder))
# {"name": "Bob", "age": 30, "attribute": {"height": 180, "width": 70}}

p = Person('Bob', 30)
print(json.dumps(p, cls=PersonEncoder))
# {"name": "Bob", "age": 30, "attribute": null}

# Десериализация пример
p = Person('Alice', 20, nationality='swede', salary=2000)
with open('/tmp/person', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(p, f, cls=PersonEncoder)

print(Person(**json.load(open('/tmp/person'))))
# <__main__.Person object at 0x7efd996c91d0>
```

Тут надо понимать, что под сериализацией в данном случае подразумевается лишь сохранение значений полей объекта. Если все поля задаются в конструкторе через принимаемые аргументы, то видно, что десериализация очень простая. Но сам объект нигде не сохраняется, поэтому по сохраненным данным создается новый. Это не `pickle`, который сможет сохранить объект и восстановать его при наличии определения класса в области видимости.

Comment: А как в таком случае десериализовать файл?

Comment: @A.Hall, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Выводит ошибку:
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Comment: Покажите, что возвращает `json.load`? И какую версию `python` используете?

Comment: Строку, поместил её в переменную temp:
https://ibb.co/kpoShJ

Python 3.6

Comment: Так, а код приведенный в ответе у вас работает без ошибок?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79731/discussion-between-a-hall-and-mkkik).