# Как серелизовать произвольный объект в строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сериализация

У меня есть произвольный объект, например упрощенно для класса:

```
class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def calc():
        return self.x + self.y
```

создаю объект:

```
attr = Attribute(1, 1)
```

Я хочу сохранить этот объект(`attr`) в строку и потом при необходимости его оттуда загрузить. Я пытался использовать модуль `pickle`, но не осилил.

```
import pickle
pickled = pickle.dumps(attr)
spickled = str(pickled)

unpickled = pickle.loads(spickled)
```

Привело к ошибке:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

`str(pickled)` потому что на самом деле я должен сохранить свой объект в `json` как строку и потом считать оттуда при другом запуске.

Собственно вопрос, как мне сохранить мой объект в json и потом его прочитать? Человекочитаемость не обязательно.

Comment: Может, написать энкодер для класса? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/850136/

Comment: @mkkik я думал о чем то подобном. Но классов на самом деле несколько и они вложенные. И могут расширяться. Хочется менее затратный универсальный способ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pickle
import base64

pickled = pickle.dumps(attr)
spickled = base64.standard_b64encode(pickled)

unpickled = pickle.loads(base64.standard_b64decode(spickled))

print(unpickled, unpickled.x, unpickled.y)
```

Comment: Только у вас байты так и остаются, а у ТС, как я понял основная проблема - запись в `json` и восстановление.

Comment: @mkkik я действительно столкнулся с проблемами из-за того, что это все еще не строка. Однако дополнительное `spickled.decode("utf-8") перед сохранением решило мои проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Если писать энкодер не вариант, значит, можно использовать менее элегантный способ:

```
import ast
import json
import pickle

class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def calc():
        return self.x + self.y

    def __eq__(self, oth):
        return self.__dict__ == oth.__dict__

obj = Attribute(1, 1)

# --- dump
object_bytes = pickle.dumps(obj)
object_bytes_str = str(object_bytes)
object_json_dump = json.dumps(object_bytes_str)
# --- dump

# --- load
object_bytes_str = json.loads(object_json_dump)
object_bytes = ast.literal_eval(object_bytes_str)
obj_from_dump = pickle.loads(object_bytes)
# --- load

print(obj == obj_from_dump)
```

Тут основная решаемая задача - получение `bytes` из строки с помощью `ast.literal_eval`.

Пока писал, появился [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/998901) от **Xander**, который куда более предпочтительнее.