# Django. TypeError: Decimal('') is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    # ...
    payout = models.DecimalField(
        _('payout'),
        max_digits=8,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )
    # ...
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='home', redirect_field_name=None)
def bank_payout(request, id):
    if request.POST:
        bank = Bank.objects.get(pk=id, user=request.user)

        if bank:
            payout = bank.payout
            request.session['payout'] = payout
            # временно редиректем дальше
            return redirect('bank_payout_success')
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**На выходе:**

```
TypeError at /cabinet/payout/
Decimal('18.92') is not JSON serializable
```

В шаблонах нормально всё выводит и в терминале (manage.py shell), но вот при попытке присвоить переменной во вьюхе, получается вот такая вот ошибка.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791712/Ошибка-typeerror-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable

Comment: Да, я видел этот вопрос. Но я не использую json, как в том вопросе. И не понятно почему в ошибке идет речь про сериализацию json'а.

Comment: Нам тоже не понятно. Простое создание переменной во вьюхе по умолчанию не делает абсолютно ничего. Вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: Можете приложить код `views.py`?

Comment: @andreymal, вы правы, но ошибка именно в этом присвоении, так как после того как сделал payout = float(bank.payout), ошибка пропала.

Comment: @Andrey, обновил код views.py.

Comment: Ну вот, у вас данные сессии кодируются в json, но decimal несовместим с json. Ошибка совсем не в этом присвоении, а в вашем использовании request.session

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо.

Comment: Вообще, читайте в документации Django про сессии. Возможно, стоит переключиться с json на pickle, и тогда хранить decimal вроде станет можно

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @andreymal, согласно документации вариант с json более безопасный чем с pickle. Как по мне, то, лучше уже воспользоваться json.dumps() и DjangoJSONEncoder.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, не совсем понял какой полный текст ошибки добавить? Он и так полный, только в заголовке убрал число и всё.

Comment: @Ins полный текст ошибки содержит traceback, позволяющий отследить всё последовательность вызовов, закончившихся ошибкой.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, так бы и написали что traceback нужен. :) Но проблема уже решена, так что вряд ли он уже нужен.